# How do I UPDATE user values from $_SESSION?

Tags: php, html, sql, session

I'm trying to make a form that allows the user to change AND add some values to their session user.

I have not made the login, it was one of my old friends. He didn't comment the code very well, and commenting is useful for me that is relative new to php and SQL.

How do I UPDATE user values from $_SESSION?

`index.php` code:

```
<?php

include('template.php');
$role = array("1"=> "admin.php", "2"=> "useradmin.php", "3"=> "user.php"); //Visar vilken sida varje roll skall skickas vid inlogg.

if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
  $query = <<<END
  SELECT email, password, userID, fname, company, tel, role FROM user
  WHERE email = '{$_POST['email']}'
  AND password = '{$_POST['password']}'
END;
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
if ($res->num_rows > 0)
{
    $row = $res->fetch_object();
    $_SESSION["email"] = $row->email;
    $_SESSION["fname"] = $row->fname;
    $_SESSION["tel"] = $row->tel;
    $_SESSION["company"] = $row->company;



$query2 = <<<END
  SELECT role FROM user 
  WHERE role = '{$row->role}'

END;
  $res2 = $mysqli->query($query2) or die ($mysqli->error);
  $row2 = $res2->fetch_object();

  header("Location: ".$role[$row2->role]);
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Fel email eller lösenord.";
  }
}
```

`settings.php` code with HTML File:

```
<?php
include('template.php');
 $content = <<<END
 <div class="row">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron">
          <div class="container">
          <h2> Användarinställningar för <strong>{$_SESSION['fname']}</strong></h2>
<form action="" metod="POST">
    <ul class="usersettings">
        <li> Förnamn: <br>
        <input type="text" name="fname" value="{$_SESSION['fname']}">
        </li>
        <li> Email: <br>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="{$_SESSION['email']}">
        </li>
        <li> Telefonnummer: <br>
        <input type="text" name="tel" value="{$_SESSION['tel']}">
        </li>
        <li> Företag: <br>
        <input type="text" name="company" value="{$_SESSION['company']}">
        </li>
        <li> 
          <input id="sparaknapp" type="submit" value="Spara">
        </li>


    </ul>
</form> 

          </div><!-- Stänger jumbotronen --> 
         </div><!-- Stänger container --> 
      </div><!-- Stänger row --> 
END;
  echo $navigation_user;
  echo $header;
  echo $content;
  ?>
```

`registration.php` code:

```
if(isset($_POST['email']))

{
function genRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $string = '”';
    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }

    return $string;
}
  $password= genRandomString();
  $licenseID= genRandomString();

    $query = <<<END

    INSERT INTO user(email, company, courseID, antal, password, licenseID)

    VALUES('{$_POST['email']}','{$_POST['company']}','{$_POST['courseID']}', '{$_POST['antal']}', '$password','$licenseID');
END;
    $mysqli->query($query);


echo 'Nya licenser har lagts till i databasen';

}
 $content = <<<END
 <div class="row">
         <div class="container">
         <div class="jumbotronadmin">
            <div class="jumbotron">

          <div class="container">

  <h2>Generera Licenser</h2>


            <form action="admin.php" method="post">
              <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name="company" placeholder="Företag">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name="email" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name="antal" placeholder="Antal licenser">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name="courseID">Webbutbildningen i Allmän brandskyddskunskap
                    </label>
                </div>

                 <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name="role">Skapa en ny administrativ användare
                    </label>
                </div>
                </div>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Beställ">
              </form>
```

The admin on the page adds new users, and not the users, thus some values are `NULL`.

Comment: Just over write the existing values. _Although I dont think thats what you hoped for in an answer_

Comment: Plain-text password and sql injection: You should really rewrite your user registration.

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: You have to have `session_start();` at the top of all pages using sessions.

Comment: Sam, you are wasting your time, read between the lines! The question actually says ___Will someone write this code for me___ @JayBlanchard

Comment: I have in include('template.php') which has the session_start();

Comment: *Thanks for the heads up Smokey!* I see it now @RiggsFolly

Comment: Update what as `$_SESSION` rather than `$_POST` **it is totally unclear what you are actually asking**

Answer (score -1):

You can update session variable by using below pattern in your code.

$_SESSION['key'] = 'value';